# Animation of Hotkey Window in iTerm2

Tags: iterm2

Is there a way to make the hotkey window animation appear smoother? Currently, I can detect it animating choppy and was wondering if there is a setting for this.

If not, perhaps someone could point me to the location in the code where this animation takes place so I can try to understand it better.